# How to implement last/recently visited functionality like google docs with mongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have two collections, user and project. And there is a many-to-many relationships between them.
One user can have multiple projects and one project can be assigned to multiple users.
Now in the user object, I have a project array to store project IDs of the projects which are assigned to that user.

Now when a user opens a project, I want to capture the timestamp. The same project can be accessed by multiple users and all of them should see only their own last accessed time. How can I implement this functionality?

user object:

```
{
    _id: ObjectID("SOME_ID"),
    name: "Name",
    email: "email@xyz.com",
    projects: [ObjectID("SOME_ID"), ObjectID("SOME_ID"), .... ]
}

project object: 
{
    _id: ObjectID("SOME_ID"),
    name: "Name",
    "desc": "Description:
}
```

Edit: The problem is I have the code implemented for the user's project at many places. If I change that array, then it will be a breaking change. Is there any other approach?

Comment: Would changing projects to an array of objects `{ id: ObjectID, viewedAt: time }` work for you?

Comment: @kausko yes it will work. But the problem is that it will be a breaking change. 
Sorry I missed adding this in the description.

Answer (score 1):

While Kausko's answer is perfect and easy if the number of projects is less. In which case you can iterate the array of objects and upsert each time a user visits a project for "last visited time". However, this is CPU expensive tasks.

**Recommended Approach**

Another approach would be to save the projects with the user as a map with the **str(Project(ObjectID))** being the **Key**  and `{ id: Project(ObjectID), viewedAt: time }` being the **value**.

This reduces the Insert complexity to O(1). The fetch complexity for both approaches remain the same

**Missed the edit - With your scenario to avoid breaking changes**

Have a map on Project Schema where str(User(ObjectID)) being the **Key** and `timestamp()` being the **value**.